# Should I upvote answer/comments that fail to address the original Q?

Tags: discussion

inexperience stackoverflow user here.

I posted a question, the one answer I got did not address my question. Neither did the follow up comments from the same person (when I tried to clarify my original question). And the person was pretty upset that I did not upvote the answer/comments.

does the effort itself deserve upvoting?

Comment: Up-voting an answer that doesn't address the question will confuse other users who have the same problem and are looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

> **What is voting up?**
>
> Voting up is how the community indicates which questions and answers
>   are most useful and appropriate.
>
> **When should I vote up?**
>
> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is
>   especially useful, vote it up!
>
> You have a limited number of votes per day, so use them wisely.

Its your choice. If the Answer wasn't helpful nor related, no need for an upvote. Stackoverflow is not about upvotes, reputation or badges - its about quality for the world.